# Yii2 $user->save не отрабатывает

Tags: php, база-данных, yii2

Yii2. Когда пытаюсь сохранить в базу данных, $user->save, то мне сервер возвращает ошибку - "An internal server error occurred." Проверял на валидацию, проверял на подключение базу данных, все нормально. Пытался делать выборку из базы данных, все делается, все выбирается, но вот не сохраняется. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: посмотри в логах что пишет.......try catch с отладкой и бряком внутри catch

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Спасибо, помогло. Выявил причину и устранил. Совсем вылетело из головы использовать эту конструкцию :)